# objectity How to handle entities within other entities

Tags: java, android, entity, backend, objectify

Good morning, I'm updating my appengine backend with objectity in an android application where I called the backend from an asincona class.
After reading several tutorials, I have managed to get, update, insert and delete an entity, but this entity contains an arraylist of another type of entity, and when I want to do a get there is no problem since the main entity gives me access to The list of entities, I have even managed to do the insert, but at the time of doing update and delete I can not get it to work.

example entity user has a list of photo entities:

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
@Id
String id;
private String mail;
private String name;
private ArrayList<PhotoEntity> listPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

//constructor
public UserEntity(){}

getters & setters....
}
```

the photo entity:

```
@Entity
public class PhotoEntity {
@Id
Long id;
private String author;
private int height;
private int widht;
private Blob image;

//constructor
public PotoEntity() {}

getters & setters.....
}
```

Endpoint of UserEntity

The insert method works:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "insertUserPhoto",
        path = "userEntityPhoto",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public UserEntity insertUserPhoto(@Named("idUser")String idUser, UserPhotoEntity userPhoto) throws NotFoundException {
    UserEntity userEntity = null;
    userEntity = ofy().load().type(UserEntity.class).id(idUser).now();
    if (userEntity == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Could not find UserEntity with ID: " + idUser);
    }
    userEntity.getListPhotos().add(userPhoto);
    ofy().save().entity(userEntity).now();
    logger.info("Created UserPhotoEntity with ID: " + userPhoto.getId());

    return ofy().load().entity(userEntity).now();
}
```

The update method does not work:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "updateUserPhoto",
        path = "userEntityPhoto/{id}",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.PUT)
public UserEntity updateUserPhoto(@Named("idUser") String idUser,
                                          @Named("idPhoto") String idPhoto) throws Exception {

    UserEntity userEntity = null;
    UserPhotoEntity userPhotoTemp = null;

    userEntity = ofy().load().type(UserEntity.class).id(idUser).now();
    if (usuarioEntity == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Could not find UserEntity with ID: " + idUser);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < userEntity.getListPhotos().size(); i++){
        if(userEntity.getListPhotos().get(i).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(idPhoto)){
            userPhotoTemp = userEntity.getListPhotos().get(i);
            userPhotoTemp.setAuthor("code changed");

            userEntity.getListPhotos().get(i).remove();
            userEntity.getListPhotos().add(userPhotoTemp);

            ofy().save().entity(userEntity).now();
            break;
        }
    }

    logger.info("Updated UserPhotoEntity: " + userEntity);
    return ofy().load().entity(userEntity).now();
}
```

The delete method does not work:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "removeUserPhoto",
        path = "userEntityPhoto/{id}",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.DELETE)
public void removeUserPhoto(@Named("idUser") String idUser,
                                 @Named("idPhoto") String idPhoto) throws NotFoundException {

    UserEntity userEntity = null;

    userEntity = ofy().load().type(UserEntity.class).id(idUser).now();
    if (userEntity == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Could not find UserEntity with ID: " + idUser);
    }

    for(UserPhotoEntity upe : userEntity.getListPhotos()){
        if(upe.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(idPhoto)){
            ofy().delete().entities(upe);
            break;
        }
    }

    logger.info("Deleted UserEntity with ID: " + idPhoto);
}
```

Someone can help me, how should I manage the endpoint methods when there is a list of entities?

thank you.

Comment: You need to read up on the difference between embedding data and referencing data with `Key` or `Ref`. It looks like you're trying to treat embedded data as a reference. https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities

Answer (score 0):

That will create and embedded entity I suggest that you change to Ref:

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
@Id
String id;
private String mail;
private String name;
private List<Ref<PhotoEntity>> photoEntity= new ArrayList<Ref<PhotoEntity>>();
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Parameterized type com.googlecode.objectify.Ref<com.myapp.backend.PhotoEntity> not supported.

Comment: I try to put this anotation in getters and setters and compile @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE) but now in my app code that not appear the method to set the list

Comment: the question is why get and insert method (using list of entities) work and update and delete not work?